# How to draw the following symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

I want to draw the 'T' like symbol of the following document,

[image]

I tried using `\mathcal`, `\mathfrak` but it didn't work. I also tried to use [detexify](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjQuMDAwvzKAhXLcI4KHcyWA4QQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdetexify.kirelabs.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNHJcuTHa35zBnkCkKDQZX2U9KjODg&sig2=35r83cXOEYkQsus2gsX_RA&bvm=bv.114195076,d.c2E) but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I suppose you are aware of this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character ?

Comment: Looks like something from the package `eucal` (or `euscript`?).

Comment: @campa: How to use that?

Comment: @user170039, load `\usepackage{eucal}` and then `$\mathcal{T}$`

Comment: @user170039, could you state your suggestion as answer, so it can be accepted, please.

Comment: @StefanPinnow: My suggestion? Of what?

Comment: I am sorry, Of course I meant @Sigur that he should state _his_ comment as answer.

Comment: I suggest @campa to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glyph you are looking for comes from the Euler script symbols. You can use it by writing in the preamble

```
\usepackage{eucal}
```

which redefines `\mathcal` to provide the Euler script symbols. The original meaning of `\mathcal` is saved in the macro `\CMcal`. Alternatively, you can call the package with the option `mathscr`

```
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
```

This leaves `\mathcal` untouched and provides `\mathscr` to access the Euler script symbols.

Another alternative (which the documentation seems to consider obsolete) is to call

```
\usepackage{euscript}
```

which leaves both `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` untouched and simply provides `\EuScript`.